# CSVMapper and CSVSchema throwing error for Quotes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-csv

I am getting error when I try to parse my csv file, This is error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): Expected separator ('"' (code 34)) or end-of-line

and this is my csv file line that throws the error

> SOME NAME|BULGARIA|123444|"abc def ghijkl, abcdef abcd abc., efg, 8 "hi. jk. lmnopqrst" abcd, we-2636 abcdffe, bulgaria"|0|Abcdef ghui Llmnopqres.|"0 "hi. jk. Wertyyi" abcd"|Abcdef|""|WE-2636|yahoo|call|"123444|1|Abcd"|WE_4981878

Sorry for the long line

Here is syntax

```
csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(User.class)
                    .withUseHeader(true)
                    .withColumnSeparator("|")
                    .withQuoteChar('\"')
```

But this is not working but the same syntax is working for `"Aple \"Abcd Abcd Abcdefghijk\""`
Also I can't use `withoutQuoteChar`because my line contains `"123444|1|Abcd"`

Comment: `.withQuoteChar('\"')` should be `.withQuoteChar('"')`.

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the minimal example of User class to reproduce it?